# Is there a way to select a single line/word of a multi-line string in a textblock/textbox object?

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, textbox, textblock

At the moment I am making an editor that would help create xml files. At the moment I store the whole document as a string that is updated every time an addition is made. The way the user could update the document is through a separate system. This is all displayed to the user using a textblock which isn't editable as the 'editing' part is being controlled by that separate system.

However, I want the user to be able to select the visual display of the xml document (which is just a string) and somehow store that line of xml code. Below I have edited an extract of what I am working with. With just that string of xml inside a textbox/texblock I want the user to be able to select  or highlight the whole line 'tag datapoint="something" value="0" ' and then assign it to a string variable.

```
<group name="DefaultSettings">
        <tag datapoint="something" value="0" />
        <tag datapoint="something" value="9"/>
        <tag datapoint="somethingElse" value="10"/>
        <tag datapoint="somethingElse" value="11"/>
</group>
```

My initial idea was to temporarily store what has been created so far as an xml file and then search that file, but I still would need specific input on what node the user would want to edit/add another node after or before which is only possible with a search bar. This option would be no different than a search function in a text editor.

Ultimately, if this idea is possible it would provide the most intuitive way to receive user input.

At the moment I would say I don't need a solution but any ideas or suggestions about what I can look into are welcome!

Comment: Hello, do you mean how to set the selected text of TextBlock/TextBox by code?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the actual question is. You cannot edit the xml file, but you still want to allow the user to make changes? If you allow the user to make any changes you will risk concurrency issues if the file is updated from two different systems. Or are you after something like a patch where an "edit" is stored separately?

Comment: Hi all! For Richard first, I don't mean that as that is how I am already displaying the file (in a textbox that I update). For JonasH, I can see I probably didn't use the right terminology with the "different system". That "system" is a set of text boxes for each xml attribute that the user can fill in and then add/update the file. This is within the same app (system in your case) and works really well. My question is really just about developing some way to work with what I have already built and somehow let the user select a string within a bigger string that is all displayed in a textbox.

Comment: Hello, Is it a problem you encountered in development? Can you provide some pictures or reference materials for similar functions to let me understand your intentions?